# Iterating through a double array in Mustache

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I have a double array that I'm passing into my Mustache file and the first two levels are indexed by number.  The variable name is `{{groups}}` so I can iterate through the outer part with `{{#groups}}{{/groups}}` but within each group is an array of questions.

I want to be able to iterate through each question and create some html for each. How can I do this if the references are numerical?

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier to give you an answer if you provided some code and/or data examples, but the gist of it is that you need an [implicit iterator](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags#implicit-iterator):

```
{{# groups }}
  {{# . }}
     <!-- this section will happen once per element in each element of groups -->
  {{/ . }}
{{/ groups }}
```